# Gprof shows regular functions in the app as called from <spontaneous>

Tags: c, profiling, gprof

So - I've been writing a language interpreter as a side project for a year now. Today I have finally decided to test its performance for the first time! Maybe I should have done that sooner... turns out running a Fibonacci function in the language takes x600 the time of the equivalent Python program. Whoopsy daisy.

Anyway... I'm off to profiling. In the call graph, `gprof` regards a few functions (namely critical ones) as called from `<spontaneous>`. It's a problem because understanding what calls these functions the most frequently will aid me.

I compile the project as a whole like so:

```
gcc *.c -o app.exe -g -pg -O2 -Wall -Wno-unused -LC:/msys64_new/mingw64/lib -lShlwapi
```

I use `gprof` like so:

```
gprof app.exe > gprofoutput.txt
```

Since it's a language interpreter, many of these functions (all of them?) might be called as part of a mutual recursion chain. Is it possible that this is the problem? If so, is `gprof` to be trusted at all with this program?

The functions called by `<spontaneous>` are compiled as part of the `*.c` files of the project, and are not called by an external library or anything that I know of.

Because I have checked this, the other answers here on SO about `<spontaneous>` haven't solved my issue. What can be causing these functions to appear as called from `<spontaneous>` and how can I fix this?

Example `gprof` output (`_mcount_private` and `__fentry__` are of course irrelevant - including them here in case it grants any clues):

```
index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     46.9    1.38    0.00                 _mcount_private [1]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[2]     23.1    0.68    0.00                 __fentry__ [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[3]     18.7    0.06    0.49                 object_string_new [3]
                0.17    0.24 5687901/5687901     cell_table_set_value [4]
                0.00    0.08 5687901/7583875     make_native_function_with_params [7]
                0.00    0.00 13271769/30578281     parser_parse [80]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.17    0.24 5687901/5687901     object_string_new [3]
[4]     14.1    0.17    0.24 5687901         cell_table_set_value [4]
                0.12    0.05 5687901/5930697     table_set_value_directly [6]
                0.02    0.04 5687901/7341054     table_get_value_directly [9]
                0.01    0.00 5687901/5930694     object_cell_new [31]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[5]      7.0    0.07    0.14                 vm_interpret_frame [5]
                0.01    0.05 1410341/1410345     cell_table_get_value_cstring_key [13]
                0.01    0.02  242786/242794      cell_table_set_value_cstring_key [19]
                0.02    0.00 3259885/3502670     object_thread_pop_eval_stack [22]
                0.01    0.00  242785/242786      value_array_free [28]
                0.00    0.01  242785/242785      vm_call_object [34]
                0.00    0.00  681987/1849546     value_compare [32]
                0.00    0.00  485570/31306651     table_init [20]
                0.00    0.00  242785/242788      cell_table_free [38]
                0.00    0.00  242785/25375951     cell_table_init [29]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           object_load_attribute [50]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           object_load_attribute_cstring_key [52]
                0.00    0.00       1/2           object_user_function_new [56]
                0.00    0.00       2/33884613     copy_cstring [17]
                0.00    0.00       1/5687909     object_function_set_name [25]
                0.00    0.00       1/17063722     copy_null_terminated_cstring [23]
                0.00    0.00       1/72532402     allocate [21]
                0.00    0.00 3502671/3502671     object_thread_push_eval_stack [81]
                0.00    0.00 1167557/1167557     object_as_string [85]
                0.00    0.00  681988/681995      two_bytes_to_short [86]
                0.00    0.00  485572/485578      value_array_make [88]
                0.00    0.00  242786/242786      object_thread_push_frame [96]
                0.00    0.00  242786/242786      object_thread_peek_frame [95]
                0.00    0.00  242785/242785      object_thread_pop_frame [97]
                0.00    0.00  242785/485571      vm_import_module [89]
                0.00    0.00       2/1167575     object_value_is [83]
-----------------------------------------------

..... etc .........
```

I'm running Mingw-w64 GCC on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

From [the gprof manual](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gprof-2.9.1/html_chapter/gprof_5.html):

> If the identity of the callers of a function cannot be determined, a dummy caller-line is printed which has `' as the "caller's name" and all other fields blank. This can happen for signal handlers.

Looks like your caller's name is unknown to gprof. If any potential caller (including async dispatch, if you're using such) is compiled without symbols, the callers names would not be known. What third party libraries are you using? Can you get debugging symbols for them?

You can obtain [Windows symbol packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols), though I don't know which libraries are covered. That page also discusses using Microsoft's Symbol Server instead of downloading (potentially out-of-date) symbols packages.

Comment: I doubt that's possible -- `Shlwapi` is a proprietary Windows DLL, unlikely to have debugging information.

Comment: I don't know which libraries are covered, but you can obtain [Windows symbol packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-symbols). That page also discusses using Microsoft's Symbol Server instead of downloading (potentially out-of-date) symbols packages.

Comment: Interesting. You should probably put that in your answer in case your comment is removed for some reason.